# Start Activity from a Pdf File

Tags: android, pdf, android-activity, android-manifest

Let say i have an app named PdfManager and an activity named PdfViewerActivity. When i am in another app or the OS trying to open a pdf file, and i press the button "open file with", i want my app to appear in the list of options (Drive Pdf Viewer, Pdf Reader, etc). When my app is selected, i want the PdfViewerActivity to be started. How can i do that?

I have tried in the AndroidManifest, inside the tag of the activity like that:

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I expected this configuration will allow me to make my app part of the list of apps that can open a pdf in the option "open with" when i try to open a pdf on the system, by it didn't result.

Answer (score 1):

You want the VIEW action, not OPEN_DOCUMENT.  You may also need to set the Activity to exported=true, but I'm not certain that's required.

OPEN_DOCUMENT is used when you want the user to select a file, not when you want your app to be used to open it.